# Pivot table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the table called table1 for example as shown below.

**Example**:

```
create table table1
( 
  slno varchar(10),
  joiningdate date,
  joiningtime time
);
```

Inserting some rows:

```
insert into table1 values('a1','09-08-2011','10:00:00');
insert into table1 values('a1','09-08-2011','10:00:00');
insert into table1 values('a2','19-08-2011','11:00:00');
insert into table1 values('a2','20-08-2011','12:00:00');
```

**Note**: Now I need to display table like following format.

```
slno   joiningdate   01  02  03   04   05   06   07   08   09   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 a1     09-08-2011                                              2
 a2     19-08-2011                                                   1
 a2     20-08-2011                                                        1
```

**Note**: 01 to 23 are the joiningtime hours.

How can I show result in the above format?

Comment: what is 1 to 23 number?

Comment: @Hardik, Its joiningtime hours.

Comment: Is it static? Is always these column remains 1 to 23.

Comment: @Hardik, Yes! You are right. Its static.

Comment: PIVOT would be the way to go. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @shree.pat18, I stuck in how to check number of hours and count it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select slno,joiningdate,[1],    [2],    [3],    [4],    [5],    [6],    [7],    [8],    [9],    [10],   [11],   [12],   [13],   [14],   [15],   [16],   [17],   [18],   [19],   [20]
from 
(
select slno,joiningdate,jTime=LEFT(joiningtime,2) from table1) as a

pivot (count(jTime) for jTime in ([1],  [2],    [3],    [4],    [5],    [6],    [7],    [8],    [9],    [10],   [11],   [12],   [13],   [14],   [15],   [16],   [17],   [18],   [19],   [20]))
pvt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your output by using Two ways in Pivot table

```
1. Static approach
2. Dynamic approach
```

Here In this scenario you can use any one of the approach.

But It is always best practice to use dynamic queries.

Here is the **Dynamic Approach** :

```
DECLARE @query AS   NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    WITH cte AS
    (
        SELECT 1 AS [Hours]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT [Hours] + 1
        FROM cte
        WHERE [Hours] < 24  
    )
    select [Hours]   
    into #tempDates   
    from cte 

    select @cols =  STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([Hours])   
        from 
        #tempDates ORder by [Hours]      
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE   
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   
        ,1,1,'') 

    select @query = 'select 
                    slno,
                    joiningdate, 
                    '+@cols+'
                    from 
                    (
                    select slno,joiningdate,jTime=LEFT(joiningtime,2) from table1
                    ) 
                    as a                
                    pivot 
                    (
                    count(jTime) 
                    for 
                    jTime 
                    in 
                    ('+@cols+')
                    )
                    pvt
                    '
    execute sp_executesql @query 
    DROP TABLE #tempDates
```

Please refer following video if you are new to Pivot It is very useful video.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h3BtudZehuo

Comment: Sorry For delay to post the answer @meem

Comment: Not an issue. Thank you so much for your assistance.

Comment: Please refer above link if you are new to pivot it is very useful. I will strongly encourage you to watch that video.